# Autoplay not working in Android Firefox browser using video, object and embed tags

Tags: android, firefox, html5-video

Autoplay option using below code works fine in all browsers on all devices except Android Firefox browser

```html
<video  onload="this.play();" controls autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-dev-assets/video-and-source-tags/chrome.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-dev-assets/video-and-source-tags/chrome.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Your browser cannot play the provided video file.</p>
</video>
```

Tried below options but none of them working

1. autoplay = "1" , autoplay = "autoplay" , autoplay = "true" for video option
2. Same issue using object and embed tags (only video background appears but not autoplay)
3. On load method has no effect in android browser

No issues on chrome and Safari browsers

Codepen url for reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mdEZabp

Comment: Same issue with Firefox 106.0b3, though Autoplay is set to "Block audio and video" (setting confirmed by tapping on the lock in the address bar). So I've reported a bug: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/27270

Answer (score 0):

On Android Firefox Autoplay is controlled by the user in the settings under 'site permissions' and the default is 'Block audio and video'.

You can test this with your codeine example above by:

- load your codepen link on dedfault settings and video will not play as you observed.
- Got to option dots at the right of the URL bar, select 'Settings', then 'Site permissions', then 'Autoplay'
- Change the setting to 'Block Audio only'
- Exit settings and reset your codepen link and you video should autoplay now